# UX Reason why there aren't any "Search for project" feature in portfolios?

Tags: website-design, search, portfolio

I'm curious what is the UX reason of not including a "search for project" feature in portfolio websites?

I find most featured websites found in places like awwwards doesn't integrate a "search for project" feature, whereas in EC websites these are found on a regular basis.

What is the reason for this, and should you be integrating such features in portfolio websites?

Comment: There are no rules. You can add one if you want one, and you can not add one if you don't want one.

Answer (score 1):

That's not true.

This is the [Coroflot](https://www.coroflot.com/projects) link for "search for projects".

[image: Coroflot]